# Path only on textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

Is it possible to enter only a File path in textbox using c# (windows application)?
Just like the function (IsNumeric) that will only allow the numbers only in textbox. How should I do that?

Comment: Hi Alexis, File Path can contain any type of data, so I'll suggest to use simple textbox of winform for showing File Path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two properties of TextBox you can make use of

```
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.FileSystem;
```

This will make your textbox to provide suggestions while you type a path

Comment: Hi Nishil. Thank you for your answer again.

Comment: You are welcome. Also you can use System.IO.File.Exists(filepath); to check if the file exists or not

Comment: OK SIR! :D Thanks. I remember you. HAHAHA you already help me last time on How to show the array list on listview. Thank you very much sir. God Bless.

Comment: Always happy to help